# Integrate PHPTAL template engine into yii framework

Tags: php, yii, phptal

I'm wondering that how to integrate PHPTAL into yii framework? I'm using PHPTAL for a long time and it's nice template engine. Although Yii allows integrate another template engine into framework but it still does not support PHPTAL.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this extension for Smarty template engine: [smarty-view-renderer](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/smarty-view-renderer)

Basically, you write a Component for Yii that implements `IViewRenderer`. Then override `init()` and implement `renderFile()`, and then in your `main.php` config file, you set `viewRenderer` to your Component class. Something like this:

```
'components' => array(
    ...
    'viewRenderer'=>array(
        'class'=>'application.extensions.path.to.your.class',
        'fileExtension' => '.ext',  // file extension to be handled by PHPTAL
        //other configurations for your component
    ),
```

and it will work like a charm.

But if you don't insist on PHPTAL, Smarty is there ready for you.

Comment: That means I have to write a extension? Anyway thanks for your helps

Comment: Yes, you have to write an extension. It'll be a simple one. No problem. ;)