# Trying to template a view file in Yii with SmartyViewRenderer

Tags: php, yii, smarty

I am trying to use SmartyViewRendere in Yii. I got everything setup according to the instructions for using Smarty with Yii.

In my application I want to render a template called widgets_sidebar_template.tpl

```
<h1>Widgets bewerken voor Sidebar #<?php echo $model->id; ?></h1>
<?php $this->render('widgets_sidebar_template', array(
        'available_widgets'=>$available_widgets
    )
) ?>
```

This works fine.

Then the widgets_sidebar_template.tpl file:

```
$smarty->assign('availables', $available_widgets);
?>
<article id="widgets_container">
    <ul id="available_widgets" class="connect">
    <span>Beschikbaar</span><br><br>
    {foreach from=$availables key=k item=available}
        <li>{$available}</li>
    {/foreach}
    </ul>

    <ul id="active_widgets" class="connect">
        <span>Actief</span><br><br>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</article>
```

This file gives the error

```
Undefined index: availables
```

So the first thing that came up to me is that I needed to make sure $available_widgets is an array. So I figured that out and I am 100% sure it's an array with data. Then I checked if the $available_widgets is actually assigned to 'availables' ($availables), so i removed the:

```
$smarty->assign..
```

This gave me the same error as it was, so my guess is that i'm doing something wrong with the assigning of the 'availables' smarty array.

I hope one of you guys can give me some more advice based on this intel. Thanks:)

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any particular reason you want to use smarty with Yii?

Comment: With lots of data sent through the render method, which is the case in my project, your views are becoming much more readable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170370/integrate-phptal-template-engine-into-yii-framework

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `$smarty->assign` in a smarty template. Also PHP tags will not work inside Smarty templates.
I guess you are talking about this SmartyRenderer: https://github.com/yiiext/smarty-renderer

The latest version requires Smarty version 3 or higher, it might not work with Smarty 2.

For your template you can use the following syntax to assign a variable value in Smarty:

```
{$availables=$available_widgets}
```

In your example you might even just use `$available_widgets` in the foreach loop.